# Overwriting existing files while doing a cvs checkout

Tags: ant, cvs

I have an Ant script which does a CVS- checkout every time the application needs to be deployed.
The ideal way to do this would be to delete the existing local code first and then do a checkout, but it seems I am not able to delete the project since my build file is also a part of it.
So I want to do a checkout where my existing files will be replaced by the ones in the repository.
Is there a way to force a cvs checkout which would overwrite the existing files?

My build target looks like

```
<target name="deploy.branch" depends="checkPropertyForBranch" if="branchPropertyExist">
        <record name="log.txt" action="start" />
        <echo message="${release.number}" />
        <antcall target="tag.branch" />
        <antcall target="checkout.branch" />
        <antcall target="stopJboss" />
        <antcall target="stopRemoteJboss" />
        <sleep seconds="10" />
        <antcall target="replaceTag" />
        <antcall target="deploy" />
        <antcall target="moveConfigFiles" />
        <antcall target="promote" />
        <parallel>
            <antcall target="startJboss" />
            <antcall target="startRemoteJboss" />
        </parallel>
        <antcall target="waitForWebSite" />
        <antcall target="mailSuccessBranch" />
        <record name="log.txt" action="stop" />
    </target>
```

and the checkout target is like

```
 <target name="checkout.branch">
        <tstamp>
            <format property="CHECKOUT" pattern="M/d/yyyy, hh:mm:SS a, z" locale="en" />
        </tstamp>
        <property name="checkout_start" value="${CHECKOUT}" />
        <echo message="CVS checkout of BRANCH: ${branch_tag}" />
        <!--<delete dir="${basedir}"/>-->
        <cvspass cvsroot="cvsroot" password="*****" />
        <cvs cvsroot="cvsroot" command="co -r ${branch_tag} project"dest="${checkout.dir}"  />
    </target>
```

The build.xml is present at `project/scripts/build.xml`
Where the `basedir` is `../` ie `"project"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that better than force cvs checkout will be just to delete files before checkout. You can use `<delete/>` task and exclude files which shouldn't be deleted. Try this:

```
<project name="cvs.test">

    <dirname property="base.dir" file="${ant.file.cvs.test}"/>

    <target name="cvs.checkout" depends="clean">
        <!-- here is the checkout -->
    </target>

    <target name="clean">
        <delete dir="${base.dir}">
            <exclude name="build.xml"/>
        </delete>
    </target>

</project>
```

Comment: I did try this before as a part of the checkout target, and it works well only when the checkout target is run, ie. it first deletes all the files and then does a checkout. But when whole thing is run, ie deploy, it fails saying "Unable to delete directory"

Comment: I also tried a few variations of delete, because i thought may be it was the cvs delete tag. I tried "<exec command="${delete.code}"/>" and the command was stored in the properties file as "rm -rf ../../". But both the commands do a partial delete and terminate the build with an error

Comment: Can you show us your build and structure of your project directory?

Comment: Have you tried to call `clean` task just before `checkout.branch`?

Comment: It worked!!... It seems that I did no exclude build.properties file while deleting

Answer (score 0):

Check the build script into the project, then you can delete the source project and checkout.

Comment: My build.xml is already a part of the code, and it checked in

Comment: Do you the necessary permissions to delete the files?

Comment: Yes, when i run my checkout target, it works well (delete and co). But when the deploy target is run which in turn runs the checkout target, then it fails.